# Low to high frequency conversion in panel data in R using tempdisagg

Tags: r, panel-data

I have daily panel data with four variables: date, cusip(id identifier), PD (probability of default), and price. PD is only available on a quarterly basis for the first day of January, April, July, and October. I want to generate daily data for PD using Chow-Lin frequency conversion from `tempdisagg` package. I know how to apply `td()` function on time series, but I didn't find examples with panel data frames. Here are my code and sample data using `reproduce()` from `devtools` package, so only few sample days are included instead of full quarter. Running `td()` reports an error:

> Error in td(PD ~ price, conversion = "first", method = "chow-lin-fixed", fixed.rho
>   = 0.5) :    In numeric mode, 'to' must be an integer number.

I know that both price and PD are high-frequency daily indicators in `mydata`, so I guess I need to use `to.quarterly()` function on `PD`or something similar.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(tempdisagg)
library(tsbox)

mydata <- structure(list(date = structure(c(13516, 13516, 13517, 13517,13518, 13518, 13521, 13605, 13605, 13606), class = "Date"), cusip = c("31677310","66585910", "31677310", "66585910", "31677310", "66585910", "31677310","66585910", "31677310", "66585910"), PD = c(0.076891, 0.096,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.094341, 0.08867, NA), price = c(40.98, 61.31,40.99, 60.77, 40.18, 59.97, 39.92, 59.96, 38.6, 60.69)), row.names = c(6L,13L, 36L, 43L, 66L, 73L, 96L, 1843L, 1866L, 1873L), class = "data.frame") 

mydata <- mydata%>%
group_by(cusip) %>%
arrange(cusip,date) %>%
mutate(PDdaily = td(PD ~ price, conversion = "first",method = "chow-lin-fixed", fixed.rho = 0.5))
```

Comment: Can you try to build a reproducible example? One that includes the actual data.

See here: https://github.com/christophsax/seasonal/wiki/Creating-a-Reproducible-Example

Comment: @chris I have included a minimal sample from my data set, with two firms and two quarters in 2007 (January and April).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is not sufficient. For each disaggregation, we need at least 3 low frequency values to be able to perform a regression.
Here is an alternative example, with 3 pairs of low and high frequency series:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tempdisagg)
library(tsbox)

mydata <- ts_c(
  low_freq = ts_frequency(fdeaths, "year"),
  high_freq = mdeaths
) %>% 
ts_tbl() %>% 
ts_wide() %>% 
crossing(id = 1:3) %>% 
arrange(id)
```

Applying `td` multiple times on data in a data frame will be cumbersome.
It is easier to extract the data into two lists, one with the low and one with high frequency series:

```r
list_lf <- group_split(ts_na_omit(select(mydata, time, value = low_freq, id)), id, keep = FALSE)
list_hf <-  group_split(select(mydata, time, value = high_freq, id), id, keep = FALSE)
```

Now you can use `Map()` or `map2()` to apply the function to each pair of elements:

```r
ans <- map2(list_lf, list_hf, ~ predict(td(.x ~ .y)))
```

Transforming the disaggregated data back to a data frame:

```r
bind_rows(ans, .id = "id")
#> # A tibble: 216 x 3
#>    id    time       value
#>    <chr> <date>     <dbl>
#>  1 1     1974-01-01  59.2
#>  2 1     1974-02-01  54.2
#>  3 1     1974-03-01  54.4
#>  4 1     1974-04-01  54.4
#>  5 1     1974-05-01  47.3
#>  6 1     1974-06-01  42.8
#>  7 1     1974-07-01  43.3
#>  8 1     1974-08-01  40.6
#>  9 1     1974-09-01  42.0
#> 10 1     1974-10-01  47.3
#> # … with 206 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @ chris Thank you for your prompt reply. When applying your code,  `td` works when both high-frequency variable and low-frequency variable have a regular pattern. For `td` to work on panel data I needed to 1)  fill missing data of low-frequency series to include all days of the year or  _Error: series has no regular patterns_ occurs. 2)  either remove groups with any missing value of low-frequency series or extrapolating low-frequency series, or  `td`  reports _Error: left hand side contains NAs_, although `na.omit` removed NAs. In sum, highly balanced panel is needed before calling `td`.